# Handling async actions in Redux without any middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am experimenting with async actions, and trying to handle async actions without using any middleware. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './style.css';

const countReducer = (state = { count: 0}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INC': return { count: state.count + 1 };
    case 'DEC': return { count: state.count - 1 };
    default: return state;
  }
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
  counter: countReducer,
})

const actions = {
  inc: (async () => {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ type: 'INC' });
    }, 200)}
  );
})(),
  dec: () => ({ type: 'DEC' }),
};

const store = createStore(reducers);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props, actions);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.inc}>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.dec}>Decrement</button>
        <div>Value: {this.props.count}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ counter }) => {
  return { count: counter.count };
}

const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

You can run above code [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-playground-gfwsy5?file=index.js). This does not work as expected. Clicking on 'Decrement' decreases value by 1, but clicking on 'Increment' doesn't do anything. What's wrong in above code and how can I fix it? Is it even possible to handle async actions without using any middleware like redux-thunk?

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html, tells us that  calls to setState are asynchronous and that we must not rely on `this.state` to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Which is kind of forcing you to use the `setTimeout`. Without using Redux you can find a solution to that problem in the link i've provided. But in your case when you are using redux, you'll find in https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#why-do-i-need-this :

> Thunks are the recommended middleware for basic Redux side effects
>   logic, including complex synchronous logic that needs access to the
>   store, and simple **async** logic like AJAX requests.

This is an example for a counter https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter , but you are eventually going to deal with calls to API and other async requests, so I personnally suggest you use thunk because it gives you a better solution, more optimized, faster, and cleaner, since it has been made for situations similar to yours, so no need for you to look for your own workaround. I hope this is helpful.